# How to get roughness of the material in UE4?

Tags: unreal-engine4

Is it possible to get the roughness value of the impact point(if there are any) on any material using ray-trace.

```
// shooting laser
GetWorld()->LineTraceSingleByChannel(
        HitInfo,
        LidarBodyLoc,
        EndTrace,
        ECC_MAX,
        TraceParams,
        FCollisionResponseParams::DefaultResponseParam
      );
auto row = *(HitInfo).GetComponent()->GetMaterial(0)->GetBaseMaterial()->Roughness;
```

The above code generates errors. Is there any other way I can get roughness or is there any flaw in the code I use?

Comment: What are the errors?

Comment: Last one line produces 21 errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
FScalarMaterialInput& Input = HitInfo.GetComponent()->GetMaterial(0)->GetBaseMaterial()->Roughness;
```

or

```
auto Input = &(HitInfo.GetComponent()->GetMaterial(0)->GetBaseMaterial()->Roughness);
```

but `UMaterial::Roughness` is a `WITH_EDITORONLY_DATA` property, so it may cause compilation error since Editor data would be stripped when building package.